# Regex cannot have a number in the first position or last and must be 6-20 characters long

Tags: regex, xml

Good Morning all.
I have a regex that is not fulfilling what I need. I cannot start or end with a number. I must have at least one symbol, one upper case letter, one lower case letter and of course a number in between the outer "boundaries" I have described. The regex must be at least 6 characters long and 20 max.
Below is my regex:

```
^([^0-9](?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[_!?@#$%])[^0-9]).{6,20}$
```

The issue I am having is I cannot seem to get the number boundaries and length correct.

For example, in a regex tester this is acceptable,

```
MaA1?kss1111111
```

but is not acceptable to what I need.

But this would be acceptable,

```
Mk?1wK
```

I have no starting number and no ending number.
I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can tweak your regex to this:

```
^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[_!?@#$%])[^0-9].{4,18}[^0-9]$
```

It uses `.{4,18}` (2 less than your length requirements) due to the reason you have `[^0-9]` at start and end of your regex.

[RegEx Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/lC7oA1/3)

Alternatively (and this is my preferred solution as well) you can check for `{6,20}` length and check presence of non-digit at start/end using a negative lookahead:

```
^(?![0-9]|.*[0-9]$)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[_!?@#$%]).{6,20}$
```

[RegEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/lC7oA1/2)

Comment: You should move the first `[^0-9]` behind the lookaheads, otherwise something like `Abc?1a` wouldn't match. Personally I would also use negated character class for these lookaheads..

Comment: Good point, thanks. Yes I fixed it and also gave recommended alternate solution.

Comment: What I meant with negated character classes is something like `^(?!\d|.*\d$)(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])(?=\D*\d)(?=[^_!?@#$%]*[_!?@#$%]).{6,20}$`. It's not really pretty, but need less steps to fail for invalid samples (not really that big of a deal though).

Comment: @SebastianProske  - Your string as pasted is this `^(?!\d|.*\d$)(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])(?=\D*\d)(?=[^_!?@#$%]*[_!?@#$%]).U+200CU+200B{6,20}$`  And for validation, using `.*` is probably %15-20 faster because engines optimize it out and predict the location of the following literal. That being said, I've posted over a hundred validation regexes @anubhava , how come I don't get 35 points?